# Is my APP_KEY the only thing unique to Laravel's Crypt

Tags: laravel

I have a a property stored unencrypted and I'd like to implement that going forward this specific property is encrypted when it's saved. It's also going to be unencrypted when presented in a blade view.

My question is: is the `APP_KEY` the only thing that's unique that's used for Laravel's `Crypt` facade?

In other words: if I take the unencrypted values from production, encrypt them locally with the same `APP_KEY` and then put them back in the prod database, will I be able to then decrypt them successfully on the production server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you use the same `APP_KEY` on both (various) systems you should be able to en-/decrypt your data successfully.

> if I take the unencrypted values from production, encrypt them locally with the same APP_KEY and then put them back in the prod database, will I be able to then decrypt them successfully on the production server

Yes.

You can see this, when getting the `Encrypter` service, that it injects the config key / `APP_KEY` [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Encryption/EncryptionServiceProvider.php#L27) via calling the `parseKey` method.

So when calling the [`encrypt` method](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Encryption/Encrypter.php#L82) it already has the application key, `$this->key`, ready to be applied.